# Convert to array from database

Tags: arrays, flutter, list, dictionary

From my database, I want to get this array

```
mySelectedEvents = {
  "2022-09-13": [
    {"eventDescp": "11", "eventTitle": "111"},
    {"eventDescp": "22", "eventTitle": "22"}
  ],
  "2022-09-30": [
    {"eventDescp": "22", "eventTitle": "22"}
  ],
  "2022-09-20": [
    {"eventTitle": "ss", "eventDescp": "ss"}
  ]
};
```

These are my tables :

```
INSERT INTO `event_date` (`id`, `date`) VALUES
(1, '2022-09-13'),
(2, '2022-09-30'),
(3, '2022-09-20');

INSERT INTO `event_list` (`id`, `descript`, `title`, `id_event_date`) VALUES
(1, '11', '111', 1),
(2, '22', '22', 1),
(3, '22', '22', 2),
(4, 'ss', 'ss', 3);

[{"id":"1","date":"2022-09-13","descript":"11","title":"111","id_event_date":"1"},{"id":"2","date":"2022-09-13","descript":"22","title":"22","id_event_date":"1"},{"id":"3","date":"2022-09-30","descript":"22","title":"22","id_event_date":"2"},{"id":"4","date":"2022-09-20","descript":"ss","title":"ss","id_event_date":"3"}]
```

I tried this

```
Future<dynamic> getData() async {
    var url = 'http://xxxxxxxxxx/getEvents.php';
    var res = await http.get(Uri.parse(url));
    var response = json.decode(res.body);


    Map<String, dynamic> mySelectedEvents = Map.fromIterable(response,
        key: (item) => item['date'],
        value: (item) =>
            {'eventDescp': item['descript'], 'eventTitle': item['title']});
            
    print(mySelectedEvents);
    return mySelectedEvents;
  }
```

Comment: What are you getting results? What is actually a problem?

Comment: print(mySelectedEvents); give {2022-09-17: {eventDescp: 44, eventTitle: BYYY}, 2022-09-20: {eventDescp: 77, eventTitle: HHJ}} . only two answer

Comment: i tried   var mySelectedEvents =
        groupBy(response, (Map obj) => obj['date']).map((k, v) => MapEntry(
            k,
            v.map((item) {
              item.remove('date');
              return item;
            }).toList()));
    print(mySelectedEvents); . i have error type 'List<dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'Iterable<Map<dynamic, dynamic>>'

Answer (score 0):

I think the code that you have written is good, are you sure that your database does have more than two elements?

Comment: yes i have more than tow elements. INSERT INTO `event_date` (`id`, `date`, `selectdate`) VALUES
(4, '2022-09-17', '2022-09-17 22:13:04.508644'),
(5, '2022-09-17', '2022-09-17 23:19:05.885897'),
(6, '2022-09-17', '2022-09-17 23:19:05.885897'),
(7, '2022-09-20', '2022-09-20 00:00:00.000Z'),
(8, '2022-09-17', '2022-09-17 23:20:46.357121');   and  INSERT INTO `event_list` (`id`, `descript`, `title`, `id_event_date`) VALUES
(5, 'azerty', 'azertyui', 4),
(6, '11', 'AZE', 5),
(7, '22', '4556', 6),
(8, '77', 'HHJ', 7),
(9, '44', 'BYYY', 8);  It's supose to group by date

Comment: i tried  var mySelectedEvents =
        groupBy(response, (Map obj) => obj['date']).map((k, v) => MapEntry(
            k,
            v.map((item) {
              item.remove('date');
              return item;
            }).toList()));
    print(mySelectedEvents); but i have error type 'List<dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'Iterable<Map<dynamic, dynamic>>'

Comment: Don't rely on `json.decode` try to implement you own model class, I believe that would solve this.

Comment: no good result with  class Event {
  String? date;
  String? descript;
  String? title;

  Event(
    this.date,
    this.descript,
    this.title,
  );
  Event.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    date = json['date'];
    descript = json['descript'];
    title = json['title'];
  }

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
    final Map<String, dynamic> data = new Map<String, dynamic>();
    data['date'] = this.date;
    data['descript'] = this.descript;
    data['title'] = this.title;
    return data;
  }
}